# Update DateTime manually

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

Since I'm hassling to much with the `timestamp` I would like to use `dateTime`. But since `dateTime` doesn't offer the auto update, I need to do it manually. But my `NOW()` doesn't do anything to my row.

```
function user_activity($active){
    $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE memory SET
    page = ? AND activity2 = NOW() WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['id']}' ");
    $values = array($active);
    $query->execute($values);
    $counts = $query->rowCount();
    return $counts;
}
```

Comment: hi what is the `)` next to `NOW()` function for?

Comment: @mongotop sorry, typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `AND` in your `SET` statement, instead use a comma.  It also looks like you have too many `)` in your query.

```php
function user_activity($active) {
    $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE memory SET page = ?, activity2 = NOW() WHERE user_id='{$_SESSION['id']}' ");
    $values = array($active);
    $query->execute($values);
    $counts = $query->rowCount();
    return $counts;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! almost trowed the computer out the window :)

Answer (score 1):

As Phil mentions, you have a query error here. Always use exception handling when executing SQL queries.

Learn [Exception Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: I was just looking up the best practice on [PDO error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) to add to my answer; but since there's no reports of exceptions it probably won't help much here.

Comment: it would be great if you can edit your Answer and write something about the best practices on PDO error handling, so that programmer immediately get to know that somewhere in the program a query error has occured. :)